# TypeError with jQuery FLOT v 0.8 but not with v0.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, flot

I am using the jQuery FLOT plugin to plot some data.  The tool that I am using to save the image is [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/). This small library lets you save a HTML5 canvas element as an image file. This code is working on my page and I am able to save the canvas element.

The problem I was having was that the axis labels were not part of the canvas, and were therefore not being saved as part of the image.  I then learned that FLOT 0.8 supports drawing axis labels to canvas using the [canvas plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/canvas/index.html).  Since I had been using FLOT 0.7, I updated the library to the new version 0.8, and now I am getting an error:  `TypeError: options.grid.borderWidth is null`.

When I switch back to version 0.7 of FLOT, the error message goes away, but with version 0.8 I get the error.  I know that the div containing the flot plot needs to have the width and height specified, which is why I am using this:  `<div id="flot" style="height:10px; width:10px;"></div>`.

In addition to specifying the width and height of the plot area in the HTML, I also specify it again on the success callback of my AJAX method.  Here is the code for that:

```
$("#flotAverageSalePricesCity").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
if (data){
$.ajax({ 
    url: sURL + "utility/ajaxmuniChart1c",
    type: "POST",
    data: {muni: data[0]},
    dataType: 'json',               
    success: function(json){
        if  (data) {                    
            myWidth =  (document.getElementById('flot_widget').offsetWidth-45)+"px";
            myHeight = (document.getElementById('flot_widget').offsetWidth*.66)+"px";
            document.getElementById('flot').style.width = myWidth;
            document.getElementById('flot').style.height = myHeight;                    
            var options = {
                series: {
                    lines: { show: true, fill: false, fillColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)" },
                    points: { show: true, fill: true }
                }
            }; 
            var xxx = $.plot("#flot", [json], options);         
            var ctx = xxx.getCanvas();              
            cb = $('#flot').find('canvas.base');       
            canvas = cb.get(0);
            loc = sURL + 'php/saveme.php';
            var cs = new CanvasSaver(loc);                  
            var btnSave = cs.generateButton('Save', canvas, 'PTS_Chart');                   
            c3.appendChild(btnSave);
            var btnSave2 = cs.generateButton('Save2', ctx, 'PTS_Chart2');                   
            c3.appendChild(btnSave2);
        }
    }
})
}
})
```

Can someone explain why I might be receiving this error?  Thanks.

[image: FLOT error]

Comment: What is the exact version of Flot that you're using?

Comment: Hi @DNS, I am experiencing the error with version 0.8.1 of FLOT.  I get no error with version 0.7.  Thanks.

Comment: I again @DNS.  I would like to let you take a look at the page with the problem, but it is behind a password-protected login.  If you have time, please email me at dan dot attard at gmail.com and I will send you the login information so you can take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: Here is the data that comes back from the success callback: data: [[2008, 48], [2009, 120], [2010, 44], [2011, 85], [2012, 42], [2013, 60]]
label: "Average Sale Price per SF for Ajax"

Comment: @DanielAttard, what is the resulting size of the `flot` div after you manipulate it's height and width with with `myWidth` and `myHeight` variables?

Comment: Oh and here's a fiddle where I've unsuccessfully tried to recreate the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/C4wwX/

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark and @DNS.  If you look at attardpropertytax.ca you will see an example of the error i am getting. Search for the municipality 'Ajax' and then click the convert button.  This is what throws the error.  Thx.

Comment: @DanielAttard, when I do that I just get `Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined`

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going on there because there are three separate places where $.plot is getting called.  I see one error on load that comes from plotAccordingToChoices in functions.js.  It's complaining about font-size being undefined, because the placeholder it's using doesn't exist.  Aside from that I don't see any errors; the 'Ajax' municipality plot works just fine.  I think you'll need to work on your Fiddle until you can narrow down what's causing it, because unless I can see it happening, there's too much going on in your code to tease it out.